# Motorola Defy in a reboot loop

Tags: battery, reboot, motorola-defy

I bought a new Motorola Defy today. The phone switches on then asks to be connected to a Google account, I try to type in my login details and it reboots.

The battery shows 100% but when in switch off it moves from 0-20 and then stays at 60%.

And the phone doesn't work when not connected to a charger. Is it a battery issue?

Comment: I would return the phone and get a different one. I doubt it is a battery issue since you say that it reboots and it does it when you go to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a day, return it back and get another one is the best solution, AFAIK.

**Update**

It's a battery issue and AFAIK, nobody in this forum is going to put fixes on battery issues. And if I were in your shoes, then I would definitely return that phone and bring back a new one from the seller.

Comment: "And the phone doesn't work when not connected to a charger.. Is it a battery issue? " - Its a battery issue and AFAIK, nobody in this forum is going to put fixes on battery issues. And If I were in his shoes, then I would definetly returned that phone and bring back a new one from the seller.

Comment: Please add that explanation to your answer -- and I'll meanwhile remove my comment :)

Comment: @updated :-)....